# Android PathShape not drawing path (Canvas/Java/Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm just trying to draw a basic triangle in Android Studio but nothing is showing up when I run the program. This is my first Android program so I don't really know what I'm doing. What is wrong with it?

```
    public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context, Display display) {
        super(context);

        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        int screenWidth = size.x;
        int screenHeight = size.y;
        int pathWidth = screenWidth / 6;
        int startWidth = screenWidth / 10;
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(startWidth, 0);
        path.moveTo(startWidth, screenHeight / 5);
        path.moveTo(screenWidth / 5, screenHeight / 5);
        path.close();
        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, screenWidth, screenHeight));
        mDrawable.setDither(true);
        int color = Color.parseColor("#ff74AC23");
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
        mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0 , screenWidth, screenHeight);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
   }



 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this, display);
        setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
    }
   }
```

Comment: The first thing I see is your `path.moveTo()` calls. The `moveTo()` method doesn't "draw" anything. It simply repositions the starting point for the next draw. After the first `moveTo()`, you likely meant `lineTo()`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!